# Mock Ktor's http client with MockK

Tags: unit-testing, ktor, mockk

I want to mock requests with ktor's http client using MockK. The problem is all the methods related to making requests with the client are `inline`, so I cannot use `coEvery` on those methods. The next thing I tried was to go through the called methods until I found a method that wasn't `inline` and then mock that. After stepping through some functions, the `HttpClient.request()` function instantiates an `HttpStatement` and then calls `execute()` on it.

```kotlin
public suspend inline fun HttpClient.request(
    builder: HttpRequestBuilder = HttpRequestBuilder()
): HttpResponse = HttpStatement(builder, this).execute()
```

If I can mock the constructor and `.execute()` functions, I can intercept the call and return my canned response. I can then check that the builder's params are correct inside of a `verify` function.

```kotlin
mockkConstructor(HttpStatement::class)
coEvery { anyConstructed<HttpStatement>().execute() } returns mockk {
    coEvery { status } returns HttpStatusCode.OK
    coEvery { body<RefreshToken>() } returns RefreshToken()
}
```

This code takes care of intercepting the `execute` call. The next step would be to verify the constructor params of `HttpStatement`. This code to verify `execute` was called works:

```kotlin
coVerify { anyConstructed<HttpStatement>().execute() }
```

Next thing is to verify the constructor params. [This pull request in the MockK repo](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/583) describes how to verify constructors:

```kotlin
coVerify { constructedWith<HttpStatement>(/* Matchers here */).execute() }
```

Note that I have to add the `.execute()` or else MockK tells me I'm not verifying anything.

```
Missing calls inside verify { ... } block.
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside verify { ... } block.
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.checkMissingCalls(VerifyingState.kt:52)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:21)
    ...
```

Ok, so just add in the matchers. However, no combination of matchers I try works. I've tried doing a bunch of constant matchers for type Any (which should match anything right?)

```kotlin
coVerify { constructedWith<HttpStatement>(ConstantMatcher<Any>(true))}
```

I've tried a matcher for `HttpRequestBuilder` and `HttpClient`

```kotlin
coVerify {
    constructedWith<HttpStatement>(
        ConstantMatcher<HttpRequestBuilder>(true),
        ConstantMatcher<HttpClient>(true)
    ).execute()
}
```

And a whole slew of others. Each time, I get this error:

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: HttpStatement(mockkConstructor<HttpStatement>(any(), any())).execute(any())) was not called
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: HttpStatement(mockkConstructor<HttpStatement>(any(), any())).execute(any())) was not called
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:63)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
    ...
```

Next thing I figured I could try would be to use an `answers` block earlier on in order to print out the types of the parameters being passed in case I was wrong, but that also runs into the "nothing being done in `every` block" error.

```kotlin
coEvery { anyConstructed<HttpStatement>() } answers {
    args.filterNotNull().map { it::class.qualifiedName }.forEach(::println)
    mockk {
        coEvery { execute().status } returns HttpStatusCode.OK
        coEvery { execute().body<RefreshToken>() } returns RefreshToken(
            accessToken = accessToken,
            expiresIn = expiresIn,
        )
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to mocking the http client? Do I have to mock something even more internal? Or do I just have to stick to using the ktor `MockEngine`?

Comment: I think the problem is that you've tried to verify the construction of a mocked constructor. You can mock an engine instead, but that's not so easy and effectively the same as using the `MockEngine`.

Comment: Also, you can use the `HttpSend` plugin to avoid making a network call by mocking a response. Here is the example https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/badac5971df50fb1cdb51706bac5c76e

Comment: @AlekseiTirman thanks for the help. I tried the HttpSend plugin and that worked just fine, but my theres the drawback of needing to mock so many methods. Looks like I'll just stick with MockEngine for now.